# Basic Collada Loading in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am attempting to load a collada file using three.js and the collada loader. I am leveraging the three.js documentation, but can't seem to get the file to render on screen. What I want to achieve is a very basic import of the collada file into a scene, no animation required. The errors I am receiving are as follows:

> unhandled Surface prop: format_hint
> Can not convert Transform of type lookat

The XHR output is showing 100% load of the .dae file, and I can browse to the location of the stored file in a browser and view it as XML. I currently have the mime type set to application/xml in IIS.

Here is my current code. What am I missing?:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>three.js webgl - loaders - collada loader</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<script src="scripts/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/ColladaLoader.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
<h1>Box Example</h1>
<p>This example loads an collada file</p>

<div id="webGL-container"></div>

<script>
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    
    renderer.setClearColor(0xff0000);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    
    camera.position.x = 40;
    camera.position.y = 40;
    camera.position.z = 40;
    
    // instantiate a loader
    var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
    
    loader.load(
        // resource URL
        'models/box.dae',
        
        // Function when resource is loaded
        function (collada) {
            scene.add(collada.scene);
        },
        // Function called when download progresses
        function (xhr) {
            console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded');
        }
    );
    
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);
    
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    $("#webGL-container").append(renderer.domElement);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Per the advice offered, here is version 2:

```js
var scene;;
var camera;
var renderer;
var loader;

function init() {
scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();


renderer.setClearColor();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

camera.position.x = 40;
camera.position.y = 40;
camera.position.z = 40;

// instantiate a loader
loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();


    loader.load(
        // resource URL
        'models/box.dae',

        // Function when resource is loaded
        function (collada) {
            scene.add(collada.scene);
        },
        // Function called when download progresses
        function (xhr) {
            console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded');
        }
    );

    camera.lookAt(scene.position);
    $("#webGL-container").append(renderer.domElement);
    
};



function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

init();
animate();
```

Update 3: I have been able to get the core .DAE file to render, but it is missing the texture (currently showing the box as all black):

```js
var scene;
var camera;
var renderer;
var box;

// instantiate a loader
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
loader.load('models//box.dae', function (collada) {

    box = collada.scene;

    box.traverse(function (child) {

        if (child instanceof THREE.SkinnedMesh) {

            var animation = new THREE.Animation(child, child.geometry.animation);
            animation.play();

        }
    });

    box.scale.x = box.scale.y = box.scale.z = .2;
    box.updateMatrix();

    init();
    animate();
});


function init() {
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

    renderer.setClearColor(0xdddddd);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    scene.add(box);

    camera.position.x = 40;
    camera.position.y = 40;
    camera.position.z = 40;

    camera.lookAt(scene.position);
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    $("#webGL-container").append(renderer.domElement);
}
```

Comment: does the file load in http://threejs.org/editor/ ?

Comment: It loads, as it does with the "Monster" Collada 3D example, but I require a more basic example of how to load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are hitting the asynchronous loading of javascript. When you call `renderer.render()` your scene is still empty because the model has not downloaded yet. Put the code you have in an `init()` function and then create an `animate()` function and call them as such:

```
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

init();
animate();
```

The variables `scene`, `camera`, `renderer` you should make global.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this without global variables? Or do you mean declare something like var scene; then scene = new Three.Scene();

Comment: I mean that those three variables have to be defined outside the `init()` and `animate()` functions (i.e. global).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Will test momentarily.

Comment: I am having the same issues. Please see version 2 above.

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Sure, before I do, did I place the right things into the init() function (see above in my original post)

Comment: I am extremely close. Currently, I can render the object, but the texture is missing. I tried to create a fiddle, but I don't have a good location to host the .dae file from.

Comment: the third line you have in your animate() should be in init(). You only need to add the container once (not every frame). Also do the same thing for the texture that you did for the animation.

Comment: Thanks for all the assistance. I am learning a ton. I am a little lost regarding how to add the texture. Am I missing a push of the texture as a function? If I swap in my file (which has the supporting files properly linked in the same directory) into the monster example, it works... I just don't know how the texture is being applied;

Comment: I dont see you texture call

Comment: I don't know how to add it. The texture is a png file denoted in the dae file. I looked at the monster example in the threejs docs, which works if I swap in my file, but couldn't figure it out yet for the code above. Any examples besides the monster for collada imports with texture that you are aware of?

Comment: sorry was away. can you update your code as it is know?